# Char invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have problems with `invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]`.
In here, I am shifting data one digit.

```
char text[]="5052.4318" ,temp;
```

When I write like this, ok, it is working but I need to read data from `array[3]`.
How can I handle this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char *array[3];

    array[3]="5052.4318";
    char text[]={array[3]} ,temp; 
    int text_len = strlen (text),i;
    for (i =0; i <=text_len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.')
        {
                temp = text[i-1];
                text[i-1] = text[i];
                text[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf ("%s\n", text); 
    return 0;
}
```

## Working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  char *array[1] = {"5052.4318"};
  size_t text_len = strlen(array[0]);
  char text[text_len + 1], temp;
  int i;
  strcpy(text, array[0]);
  for (i=0; i <=text_len - 1; i++){
    if (text[i] == '.') {
      temp = text[i-1];
      text[i-1] = text[i];
      text[i] = temp;
    }
  }

  printf ("%s\n", text); 
}
```

In here I am trying read GPS data and this data is GPRMC so firstly i need to parse these data after have to convert to google maps format(latitude need longitude).

```
$GPRMC,093612.000,A,5052.43525,N,00440.11204,E,0.0,0.0,130917,,,A*6C
```

5052.43525 is latitude value. Firstly I need to shift data like this 50.5243525.Again shift>>After divide number of 60=> 52.43525/60=0.87392083.
So result should be 50.87392083. Another problem I shouldnt use atof command for string to float value. Because I am using Coocox and is not working in Debug.Maybe I need to use null terminal. I am sharing this code which progressing  I am doing.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main ()
 {
//char buf[] 
="$GPRMC,121212,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,030611,003.1,W*6A";

char T[100];
sprintf(T, 
"%s","$GPRMC,093612.000,A,5052.43525,N,00440.11204,E,0.0,0.0,130917,,,A*6C");
printf(T);
char *buf[]={T};
int i = 0;
char *p = strtok (*buf, ",");
char *array[12];

while (p !=0)
{
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (0, ",");

}

for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
array[i];
 printf("%s\n",array[i]);
 }
 //char *array[3] = {"5052.4318"};
size_t text_len = strlen(array[3]);
char text[text_len +1], temp;
int i1;
    strcpy(text, array[3]);
for (i1 =0; i1 <=text_len - 1; i1++)
{
    if (text[i1] == '.')
    {
            temp = text[i1-1];
            text[i1-1] = text[i1];
            text[i1] = temp;
    }
}
    for (i1 =0; i1 <=text_len - 1; i1++)
{
    if (text[i1] == '.')
    {
            temp = text[i1-1];
            text[i1-1] = text[i1];
            text[i1] = temp;
    }
 }
 char *buf1[]={text};
 int i3 = 0;
 char *p1 = strtok (*buf1, ".");
 char *array1[2];

  while (p1 !=0)
  {
    array1[i3++] = p1;
    p1 = strtok (0, ".");

 }

 for (i3 = 0; i3 < 2; ++i3) {
 array1[i3];
 } double d;
 float m;
 int k=0;

 d= (atof(array1[1])/6000);
 char s[1]= {d};
 m=(atof(array1[0]));
 printf("%f\n",m);
 printf("%lf\n",d);


return 0;

}
```

Result should be 50.87392083.
I havent completed.

Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised that's the only problem you have with the code you show. Array initializers must be compile-time constants. You can't use a run-time variable to initialize an array (like you do with `text`).

Comment: Also, when you do `array[3]="5052.4318"` you are indexing *out of bounds*! The last index in the array is `2`.

Comment: `array` is an array of pointers, `array[3]` is out of bounds. You also cannot assign `"5052.4318"` to a `char*`, you should `malloc` and `strcpy` instead.

Comment: char *array[1]; array[0]="5052.4318"; it is giving ,also same error, I used strcpy but didnt work. I will try malloc!

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/xYzqFI)

Comment: The `-fpermissive` option is primarily associated with C++ (GCC 7.2.0 says: `cc1: error: command line option ‘-fpermissive’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [-Werror]`) and the `#include <iostream>` is also including a C++ header in what is nominally a C program.  Who is more confused — you or me?

Comment: @Groo, You can assign the address of a string literal to a `char*`.

Comment: @Gerhardh: yeah, that would be a [warning in C++](https://godbolt.org/g/XY3un9) actually, but the point is that OP wants to mutate the literal, so it won't work.

Comment: Sorry before i was execute in C++, because i am working C and also C++. I executed in C there is no error but there is warning:[Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast.[Warning] (near initialization for 'text[0]')But  Output is empty.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY in here I am trying read from array so i am reading many data if i read one data your solution is correct!

Comment: If you are working in C why there is an include for `iostream`?

Comment: Thnak you Guys! solved with @BLUEPIXY code :)@BLUEPIXY

Comment: Mh.. why it is off-topic? The user required debugging help providing the complete example... Maybe it can be a little unclear in words, but the code is almost self-explanatory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve but there are some problems with the first part of your code. Your initialization lines are not really correct.

I think that you are trying to "divide by 10" your string. Keeping **your algorithm**, I've fixed some of the issues to have it compiled.

```
// #include <iostream> // This is C not C++. Also you include stdio.h...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char array[] = "5052.4318"; // This initialization 
                                // one of your errors
    char * text = array + 3; // I don't know why you are pointing 
                             // fourth element of the array, but you may do
                             // in this way

    // Let's say I prefer to start from the starting of 
    // the array
    text = array;

    printf ("%s\n", text);

    int text_len = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 1; i <= text_len - 1; i++) { // You will have some problem 
                                              // if you start from 0...
      if (text[i] == '.') {
        char temp; // temp is used only here, so let's define it in the
                   // only scope that needs it.
        temp = text[i - 1]; // This -1 is the reason why you may start
                            // the for from 1, instead of 0.
        text[i - 1] = text[i];
        text[i] = temp;
      }
    }

    printf ("%s\n", text); 
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out:

```
5052.4318
505.24318
```

Is that what you want to achieve?

The `for` starts from 1 to handle strings like `".1234"`.

Also: [`-fpermissive`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fpermissive-140) is a flag that controls the "dialect" of the C++ compiler. It is not something that you see when you are compiling in C. Since you included `iostream`, your compiler switched automatically to a C++ compiler. You must be really careful in this things.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char text[30]="5052.4318",temp;
    int text_len = strlen (text),i;
    //printf("%s\n%d\n",text,text_len);
    for (i =0; i <=text_len - 1; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == '.')
        {
                temp = text[i-1];
                text[i-1] = text[i];
                text[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf ("%s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to use an extra character array to achieve your desired result.